# List index out of range Error in Python in MGLTOOLS

Tags: python, error-handling

I'm running a program (MGLTOOLS) by python scripts. When I start the program, I get the following error. I don't know python. I don't understood the error.

```
    C:\Users\Goutham>set MGLPYTHONPATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\MGLTools 1.5.4
    C:\Users\Goutham>"C:\Python25\python.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\MGLTools 1.5.4
    \MGLToolsPckgs\AutoDockTools\bin\runAdt.py"
    Run AutoDockTools from C:\Program Files (x86)\MGLTools 1.5.4\MGLToolsPckgs\AutoD
    ockTools

    Welcome to Python Molecule Viewer!
    Visit http://mgltools.scripps.edu/documentation to read latest documentation.

    Resource file used to customize PMV: C:\Users\Goutham\.mgltools\1.5.4\Pmv\_pmvrc

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\MGLTools 1.5.4\MGLToolsPckgs\AutoDockTools\__init
    __.py", line 373, in runADT
        title=title, withShell= not interactive, verbose=False)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\MGLTools 1.5.4\MGLToolsPckgs\Pmv\moleculeViewer.p
    y", line 315, in __init__
        verbose=verbose, trapExceptions=trapExceptions)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\MGLTools 1.5.4\MGLToolsPckgs\ViewerFramework\VF.p
    y", line 345, in __init__
        verbose=verbose)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\MGLTools 1.5.4\MGLToolsPckgs\ViewerFramework\VFGU
    I.py", line 277, in __init__
        cnf = {"addScenarioButton": False})
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\MGLTools 1.5.4\MGLToolsPckgs\DejaVu\Viewer.py", l
    ine 675, in __init__
        cp = ClippingPlane(self.rootObject, i, self)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\MGLTools 1.5.4\MGLToolsPckgs\DejaVu\Clip.py", lin
    e 42, in __init__
        self.id = self.clipPlaneNames[num]
    IndexError: list index out of range
    hit enter to continue
```

Comment: You should provide the specific program you are running (which MGLTools) and how you are starting it

Comment: @DavidRobinson, MGL tools 1.5.4, is a bioinformatics tool, it has windows installer, a GUI that runs Python scripts. It works with only Python 2.5.2. It is supposed to give GUI when clicked on icon, but it is giving the above error.

Comment: You should change the title of this question to something like "Help with MGL Tools Error".  This is not a Python problem specifically.  It seems like you're using MGL Tools incorrectly.

Comment: @gthmgeeky: Please **update** the question and title.  Please don't add comments to a question.

Answer (score 1):

If this problem is arising as soon as you click on the GUI, you should contact MGL support and post on their forums, as StackOverflow is unlikely to be of any help (this might require a fix from the developers).

Note that the bug you are describing is described in this report:

http://mgldev.scripps.edu/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=1216

Comment: I tried there, but still have the same problem. I ll check once again. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is resolved in the RC3 build. Download it here [MGL Tools 1.5.6](http://mgltools.scripps.edu/downloads/mgltools-1-5-6-release-candidate).